# Target specific link from one div

Tags: html, css, syntax

I'm trying to make a dark theme via css for Tiktok's Chrome site and I'm having some trouble making the like button visable on the black background.
i tried using Filter:invert(1); and that worked but when you like the comment the red color is now teal.
tiktok doesn't use different divs for the different imgs so when i filter the black heart it filters the red one too. all tiktok does is switch the image links in the src. i want to specify the black img link in css to isolate it so i can filter that one and that one only.
This is the HTML of the red like button.

```
<img src="https://sf16-scmcdn-va.ibytedtos.com/goofy/tiktok/web/node/_next/static/images/liked-c7cae6d877d0cceec83f13891a4a8836.svg" class="jsx-1998704864 icon">
```

This is the one i want to isolate in css.

```
<img src="https://sf16-scmcdn-va.ibytedtos.com/goofy/tiktok/web/node/_next/static/images/unlike-c0928a8c3ac7b448ef79c4bb26aec869.svg" class="jsx-1998704864 icon">
```

This is what i have in my css

```
.like-container.jsx-1998704864 .icon.jsx-1998704864{
    filter:invert(1);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript? There is most likely a LocalStorage value to keep track of the dark/light mode setting.

Comment: no i am exclusively using css.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not able to use JavaScript, your best option is to use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Please note that the source is probably very likely to change, since those classnames for example seem to be auto generated by some compiler. Same goes for the image URL.

To select the unlike button use

```
img[src="https://sf16-scmcdn-va.ibytedtos.com/goofy/tiktok/web/node/_next/static/images/unlike-c0928a8c3ac7b448ef79c4bb26aec869.svg"] {
    /* your unlike button style */
}
```

For the like button use

```
img[src="https://sf16-scmcdn-va.ibytedtos.com/goofy/tiktok/web/node/_next/static/images/liked-c7cae6d877d0cceec83f13891a4a8836.svg"] {
    /* your unlike button style */
}
```

EDIT (after 15 mins):
If you want to select any image tag which contains the word "unlike" you can also use this:

```
img[src*="unlike"] {
    /* your unlike button style */
}
```